# Grub rescue error

Tags: linux-mint, mount, grub

I was using Linux mint and windows 10 together(in different partitions). Few months I was using freely. Today I got a message in windows 10(new updates available or shutdown and update) then, I clicked on shutdown and update. After finishing the update 50% automatically restarted my laptop. It happens multiple times when we install windows 10. Since than I am unable to start my laptop
[image]

I am not sure why this happens as far as I know this happens when there's no grub loader.

Here what I tried
[image]

I was watching some videos and searching on Google how to fix it. I got an solution I amt not sure it will work or not they took a live USB and they had windows on there USB but, I have Linux mint in my USB will it work?
https://youtu.be/xx2CFufykB0

I am using live USB(Linux mint). I was trying to mount linux disk. `sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt`. Then, I get an error `mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

`Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type /dev/sda1  *      1026048 272532369 271506322 129.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT /dev/sda2       272533504 273694719   1161216   567M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE /dev/sda3       273696768 274747391   1050624   513M  b W95 FAT32 /dev/sda4       274749438 625141759 350392322 167.1G  5 Extended /dev/sda5       623144960 625141759   1996800   975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris` 
[image]

/dev/sda4 is linux. I am sure for disk size

[image]

[image]

When I use Windows 10 above disk are visible without linux mint disk. When I use Linux Mint every disks are visible. Here something happening like this.

Comment: There are many ways to fix this. One of the easiest way in my opinion is to use https://sourceforge.net/projects/supergrub2/ to boot into Linux, then use `grub-install` and `update-grub` to re-install and re-configure GRUB.

Comment: @Hermann Look I am on Linux mint from live USB. How can I solve it now? I was trying `sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt` to mount my linux disk. Then, I get an error `mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.` Even, I was trying to mount it manually from file manager but, there's no disk like this. But, I found windows 10. When I tried `grub-install` from terminal I get an error. `Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: install device isn't specified.`

Comment: @Hermann I tried `sudo grub-install /dev/sda4` Error :`Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.` I tried [it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1303865/1166068) also. Then, what to do?

Comment: after `set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub` you must `set root=(hd0,msdos7)` , i wrote `msdos7` as example you have to find your real root partition.
take a look at this link:  https://paolozaino.wordpress.com/2017/12/09/how-to-fix-grub-boot-loader-after-a-windows-update-on-dual-boot-systems/

Comment: sda4 seems to be an extended partition. Please paste the full partition table from `sfdisk -l /dev/sda` output.

Comment: One step at a time. It looks like `sda4` is not your Linux partition. Please use `fdisk -l` or `sudo blkid` to find it. Also please find out whether you really use legacy BIOS MBR boot style or UEFI boot style.

Comment: @JonasBerlin I have edited

Comment: @Hermann I have added info of blkid

Comment: @D'ArcyNader Actually, when I tried `ls` only. Then, there was no disk(or whatever it called i don't know) `(hd0,msdos7)`

Comment: @D'ArcyNader I tried although same error. `no such partition`

Comment: are you still on live usb? you must do `ls` from the grub rescue , like if you are booting normally. then you see what your grub rescue see.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader I wasn't. I tried `ls` from grub rescue. and, did as you said. although I got same error. So, I came again in live usb

Comment: why don't you post the output of the `ls` from grub rescue and let us help you to guess the right partition. a picture as you did before.

Comment: Sorry to say. I don't know what happened I was doing lot of things when I was in live USB something weird happened when @D'ArcyNader told me give screenshot I reboot my laptop than update started automatically but, something wrong is going on again. After doing it I am unable to open Linux mint I am only able to use windows. I will ask a question again. If anyone here knows the solution please comment. I will give information later. Cause, I am not on laptop now

Comment: Looking at the partition table for `sda` it looks like your Linux partition is gone — assuming it used to be on `sda`. There's a big approx 166 gigabyte slice of the extended partition that is not in use at the moment.  Do you know what size your linux partition used to be? In case my guess is correct (it might not), I want to clarify that by "gone" I don't mean it can't be recovered, but it might involve a bit of work.

Comment: @JonasBerlin When I have turned my laptop on I noticed that it's like my linux have gone. Yes! Linux had 166 gigabyte which is bigger than others. I am writing a question on it.

Comment: @JonasBerlin Here's the [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636577/linux-disk-have-got-empty-after-fixing-grub-rescue-error)

Comment: You have this tagged `windows-subsystem-for-linux`, so it popped up in my watched-tags list, but there's no WSL involved here - Just pure Windows and pure Linux dual-boot, right?  If so, can you remove the incorrect tag?

Comment: Ok can you provide the output of `dd if=/devsda bs=512 skip=274749438 count=1 | tail -c 66 | hexdump -C` ? It will dump the first partition table of the extended partition so I can see if there are any traces of the original partition definition there..