# How to remove grub screen on start. i have installed ubuntu on my dos machine

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub

Hello everyone I have recently installed ubuntu on my dos machine and when the installation got finished it told me to restart.

But after restarting the system is not booting into ubuntu automatically, instead i get this grub screen

I have tried other solution also but in that they select linux kernel in /boot folder

But i cant find that file either

Can someone please help me. I am attaching my screenshot and all the file contents i found

[image]

Comment: Listen you answered your question by editing your question.. It would be better if you answer this question. Cause, others may face the issue also. So, it would be better if you answer this question rather than editing question...!

Comment: sure thanks for guiding .. actually i am new to this community

Comment: In addition, can you please transcribe the text of your screenshot in to text? Not all our users can view images (some are visually impaired, and others might be accessing the site from a pure text system as their main graphical system is down and they are trying to find a way to fix it...) You can find help on Markdown formatting codes to format the text via the various "Help" links.

Answer (score 0):

```
set
set boot=(hd0,msdos6)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
insmod
```

If insmod doesn't work than try

```
insmod nomal
reboot
```

You can read my question also. [Grub rescue error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636502/grub-rescue-error)

As you said in a comment that you have bootable USB. Linux Mint is a community-driven Linux distribution based on Ubuntu. Visit [the link](https://paolozaino.wordpress.com/2017/12/09/how-to-fix-grub-boot-loader-after-a-windows-update-on-dual-boot-systems/).

Update grub loader

```
sudo update-grub
```

For Fedora, PacketLinux or CentOS

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

6. Then verify which disk was your boot disk in Linux. To do so a quick way is to run command:

   df -l

Install grub in a specific disk(I don't remember what its called)

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Then, reboot... Now, check that are you having the issue anymore..?

Comment: Nothing happened it stills shows grub in the start

Comment: Hii this option worked for me ,, actually my files was in msdos5 ... This boots correctly but again displays this screen after reboot ... How to make this permanent ?  Can you help please

Comment: @JayeshChoudhary Do you have bootable USB? If you have then I can tell you something I tried earlier..!

Comment: Yes i have bootable usb

Comment: @JayeshChoudhary I have updated my answer..!

Comment: thank you soo much brother your answer really helped me to find right direction .

Answer (score 0):

[SOLUTION]: I have solved this issue and my ubuntu is working properly now the problem was that ubuntu was not able to find proper boot location hence it showed grub screen at the start

The problem was i think that when i installed ubuntu with erase data and install fresh option. the ubuntu referred old partitions hence was not properly pointing to the exact boot location

Then i installed ubuntu again but with selecting something else option (this option allows us to manually setup partition and delete old if we have any)

follow this youtube intallation tutorial if you are stuck in this screen
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOCQ9hEP8FM&t=202s

hope this helps